# How can i use RestSharp with maui on an ios device

Tags: c#, ios, maui

I tryed to create a simple maui app for testing:

```cs
   public MainPage()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       getcatfact();
   }

   private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       getcatfact();
   }
   private void getcatfact()
   {

           var client = new RestClient("https://catfact.ninja/");
           var request = new RestRequest("fact");
           RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
           dynamic apivalasz = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
           FactText.Text = apivalasz.fact.ToString();

   }
```

But when I tryed to run it it gived me this error (I used the newest RestSharp):

```
[0:] An error occurred: 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'. Callstack: '   at System.Net.Http.NSUrlSessionHandler.set_Proxy(IWebProxy value)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.InvokeNativeHandlerMethod(String name, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.SetProxy(IWebProxy value)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_Proxy(IWebProxy value)
   at RestSharp.RestClient.ConfigureHttpMessageHandler(HttpClientHandler handler)
   at RestSharp.RestClient..ctor(RestClientOptions options, Action`1 configureDefaultHeaders)
   at RestSharp.RestClient..ctor(Uri baseUrl)
   at RestSharp.RestClient..ctor(String baseUrl)
   at MauiApp1.MainPage.getcatfact() in C:\Users\mynamexd\source\repos\MauiApp1\MauiApp1\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 25
   at MauiApp1.MainPage..ctor() in C:\Users\mynamexd\source\repos\MauiApp1\MauiApp1\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 15
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Boolean wrapExceptions)'
The app has been terminated.
```

Then I tryed to run it on an older version (106.15.0), and than it gived me this error:

```
[0:] An error occurred: 'Could not resolve type with token 01000024 from typeref (expected class 'RestSharp.IRestResponse' in assembly 'RestSharp, Version=106.15.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75')'. Callstack: '   at MauiApp1.MainPage..ctor() in C:\Users\mynamexd\source\repos\MauiApp1\MauiApp1\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 16
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Boolean wrapExceptions)'
The app has been terminated.
```

The app runs fine on windows.
Can somebody help me how to solve this issue?

Comment: iOS does not allow the use of `dynamic`

Comment: Then what should i use, can you help me?

Comment: generally you deserialize into a C# model.  Or if you want to use `JObject.Parse`, it returns a `JObject`

Comment: Can you write me an example for that? (sry im just started c#)

Comment: replace `dynamic` with `JObject`

Comment: And how can i extract the "fact" later? ( {"fact":"a random cat fact.","length":92} ) Becaulse now it says that "JObject does not contain a definition for fact"

Comment: `jobject["fact"]`

Comment: I modified my code to this:

Comment: public MainPage()
 {
  InitializeComponent();
        getcatfact();
    }


 private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  getcatfact();
 }
 private void getcatfact()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://catfact.ninja/fact");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        JObject apivalasz = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
        FactText.Text = apivalasz["fact"].ToString();
    }

Comment: But the error still get the error
[0:] An error occurred: 'Could not resolve type with token 01000024 from typeref (expected class 'RestSharp.IRestResponse' in assembly 'RestSharp, Version=106.15.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=598062e77f915f75')'. Callstack: '   at MauiApp1.MainPage.OnCounterClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\mynamexd\source\repos\MauiApp1\MauiApp1\MainPage.xaml.cs:line 25
   at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Button.Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.IButtonElement.PropagateUpClicked()